# Shell variable inside variable

Tags: bash

What is wrong in this substitution.

```
$ m_d_ver=0.2
$ m=mod
$ d=dom
$ echo ${$m_$d_ver}
-bash: ${$m_$d_ver}: bad substitution
```

Thanks,

Comment: "What is wrong in this syntax?" -- err, that it isn't the language's actual syntax? Did you find any document or reference that made you think the original proposal *would* be allowed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're trying to do is an indirect variable lookup. The syntax for that is `${!namevar}`, where `namevar` is a variable that contains the name you actually want to evaluate. Thus:

```
mod_dom_ver=0.2
m=mod
d=dom
var=${m}_${d}_ver
echo "${!var}"
```

See [BashFAQ #006](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Indirection).

Comment: Thanks , What is this ! sign ?

Comment: It's what tells the shell to do an indirect lookup.

Comment: BTW, the curly braces here are needed because `_` is a valid character within a shell variable name, so if you wrote `var=$m_$d_ver`, the shell would be trying to expand `${m_}` and `${d_ver}`.